# Which hook do I use to alter product entity data in a product display?

Tags: commerce

In Drupal Commerce, which hook do I use to alter product entity data in a product display?**  And it needs to be a hook that fires each time I change an attribute that causes a different product entity to be loaded in the display.

I added a line item to my product type called "Comments". It is a textarea, and it has a field description too. Then, on my product type, I added the following fields:

- Customizable? (On/Off checkbox)
- Custom Field Label
- Custom Field Description

As each product entity is about to be displayed (whether it's the first one shown when the page loads, or I make a drop down selection to change which one shows), I want to check if that product entity is "Customizable".  If it is, I want to rename the title of the "Comments" line item with the value stored in "Custom Field Label".  And I want to change the Comments field description with the value stored in "Custom Field Description".  If the product entity is NOT "Customizable", then I want to hide the field completely (such as by converting the field type from a textarea to a hidden field).  This way, the "Comments" line item really only shows for the product entities we want it to, and it can have a custom label and instruction when it does show.

Any help someone can give is greatly appreciated.  I am having a lot of trouble even figuring out which hook fires each time a product entity is loaded, either the first time, or when switched via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**hook_entity_load** may be the answer that some folks are looking for in situations that differ from mine.

For my specific need, I discovered that everything I needed to accomplish could be done with **hook_form_alter**.  The form_state holds the value of the currently selected SKU in **$form_state['default_product']->sku**.  Here is a hook_form_alter function I wrote to accomplish my goals:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if(strstr($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_')) {

        // Load the current product entity
        $prod = commerce_product_load_by_sku($form_state['default_product']->sku);

        // Check and see if the produt is customizeable or not, and then react
        $customizeable = $prod->field_prod_customizable['und'][0]['value'];
        if(isset($customizeable) && $customizeable == 1) {
            // Grab the custom label and instruction
            $customize_label = $prod->field_prod_customize_label['und'][0]['value'];
            $customize_instruction = $prod->field_prod_customize_instruction['und'][0]['value'];

            // Alter the field to display the custom label and instruction
            $form['line_item_fields']['field_prod_comments']['und'][0]['value']['#title'] = $customize_label;
            $form['line_item_fields']['field_prod_comments']['und'][0]['value']['#description'] = $customize_instruction;
        }
        else {
            // If not a customizeable product, then make the field hidden and not required
            $form['line_item_fields']['field_prod_comments']['und'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'hidden';
            $form['line_item_fields']['field_prod_comments']['und'][0]['value']['#required'] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the textarea field I added to my Product line item type is called field_prod_comments.  The fields I added to my product entity are field_prod_customizable, field_prod_customize_label, and field_prod_customize_instruction.

Comment: Checkout entity_metadata_wrapper for working with commerce entities. Also, note, $product is already loaded in `$form_state['default_product']`